# How to calculate improvement of Delay (mean reduced delay) in percentage?

Tags: excel, math, delay, timedelay

I am doing a project to improve the trigger delay of a device. For example, in original methods, the trigger delay is 125 us, after i improved the original one by my method, the trigger delay reduced to 0.2 us.

So my question is, how can I calculate the trigger delay improvement of my methods over the original method in term of percentage?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Chong Han

Comment: Take a look at this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403939/how-to-calculate-percentage-improvement-in-response-time-for-performance-testing]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403939/how-to-calculate-percentage-improvement-in-response-time-for-performance-testing

Comment: You could certainly work it out (nearly 100%), but there might be a case for looking at logarithmic measures of difference like the decibel or neper.